# How to use a RecordSet.Find with TADOQuery?

Tags: delphi, ado, tadodataset

In this question:

[Delphi ADO : Locate with dataset filter on bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231727/delphi-ado-locate-with-dataset-filter-on-bug)

an ADO bug was described where the Filter string is ignored during .Locates.

This is causing problems for us migrating from the BDE because we have a lot of code that changes the filter according to user input.

We had expected TADOQuery to provide a working migration path. We were wrong.

We can of course change our current filters to WHERE statements, but that's a lot of work and risk concatenating the filter strings to filter-less WHERE statements, etc.

The accepted answer to the question linked to above suggests the possibility of using [TCustomADODataSet.Recordset.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee275542(v=bts.10).aspx)

Can we safely use RecordSet.Find in a TADOQuery just to implement .Locates? i.e. Does RecordSet.Find update whatever wrapper TADOQuery puts around TADOQuery?

If so, can someone show a sample call from Delphi XE5 to RecordSet find? I'm having trouble figuring out the arguments.

Comment: I think you late for 5 years at least for such migration. Why ADO? FireDAC seems to be most supported DB library for Delphi (if it is possible to say "support" when we speak about Emb).

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to look at the source code of ADODB.pas `TCustomADODataSet.LocateRecord`. You will see how `Locate` is implemented.

For a single condition it uses RecordSet [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee275542(v=bts.10).aspx) method. for multiple conditions it uses the [`Filter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee275540(v=bts.10).aspx) property.

Using `Find` is fairly easy:

```
uses ..., ADODB, ADOInt;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  bm: TBookmarkStr;
begin
  bm := ADODataSet1.Bookmark;
  // for partial condition use e.g. ItemName LIKE 'He*'
  ADODataSet1.Recordset.Find('ItemName = ''Hello''', 0, adSearchForward, adBookmarkFirst);
  if ADODataSet1.Recordset.EOF then // not found
    ADODataSet1.Bookmark := bm // restore bookmark
  else
    ADODataSet1.Resync([rmExact, rmCenter]); // set active record and trigger dataset change event
end;
```

Since `TADOQuery` is a `TCustomADODataSet` descendant there is no problem using `RecordSet` same as `TADODataSet`